# How do I include a code block right after a list without it turning into a blockquote?

Tags: support, markdown, code, list

If I want to write this :

```
>>> calendar = GoogleCalendar(user='blabla', password='blablabla')
>>> calendar.myFunction()
```

After a list, the >>> become a blockquote ...

- Here is the list

  > > > calendar = GoogleCalendar(user='blabla', password='blablabla')
  > > >       calendar.myFunction()

Here is the bug ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to indent it eight (8) spaces:

- Here is the list

  ```
  >>> calendar = GoogleCalendar(user='blabla', password='blablabla')
  >>> calendar.myFunction()
  ```

Which is just:

```
 - Here is the list

8 spaces>>> calendar = GoogleCalendar(user='blabla', password='blablabla')
8 spaces>>> calendar.myFunction()
```

Comment: And this is what happens when you have too many tabs open.

Answer (score 4):

Alternately put a paragraph or a non-visible HTML element as a separator between them.

**Method 1 - non-visible HTML separator**

- list item

```
i++;
```

**Method 2 - paragraph text separator**

- list item

paragraph of text here

```
i++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to indent your code by an additional 4 spaces for every level of list items.

---

- list level one

  ```
  > code block
  ```

  - level two

    ```
    > code block
    ```

    - level three

      ```
      > code block
      ```
  - level two

    ```
    > code block
    ```

Reset

```
> code block
```

---

```
- list level one

        > code block
    - level two

            > code block
        - level three

                > code block
    - level two

            > code block

Reset

    > code block
```