# Code blocks inside lists and/or list items?

Tags: support, markdown, code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I include a code block right after a list without it turning into a blockquote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30046/how-do-i-include-a-code-block-right-after-a-list-without-it-turning-into-a-blockq)

How do I create a list with code blocks in between?  Example:

1. print in ruby

   puts "ruby"
2. print in Java

   System.out.println("Java");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want short bits of code you can use backticks.

1. print in ruby

   `puts "ruby"`
2. print in Java

   `System.out.println("Java");`

Or, indent 8 spaces per [the Markdown help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

1. print in ruby

   ```
   puts "ruby"
   ```
2. print in Java

   ```
   System.out.println("Java");
   ```