# Code Block not showing up within a list

Tags: support, specific-question, markdown, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do I include a code block right after a list without it turning into a blockquote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30046/how-do-i-include-a-code-block-right-after-a-list-without-it-turning-into-a-blockq)
>   [How to nest code within a list using markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown)

I [edited this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827735/invalidoperationexception-and-workflows-in-asp-net-mvc), but even after retyping the entire entry and formatting it myself, I still can't get the codeblocks to show up.

Is there a specific reason why?

Comment: I think it's a dupe of 3792, which asks about code blocks within lists, not right after them.

Comment: Another relevant link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/why-is-a-code-block-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code within a list needs to be indented with an extra four spaces.

- Here is the list

  ```
  System.InvalidOperationException: Workflow with id "[GUID]" [...]
  ```

Which is just:

```
 - Here is the list

        System.InvalidOperationException: Workflow with id "[GUID]" [...]
```

This works for both ordered and unordered lists.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to **double-indent** (e.g., 8 spaces) the code block if it's within a list.  Here is an example of a previously asked [relevant meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown).

Comment: Great. If you add the link to the duplicate I'll vote to close with ya. :-)